# How to handle large messages in kafka via Producer side config?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Some messages from my kafka producer are larger than the default 1MB and are rejected by the broker.

I don't have access to the broker and consumer to make changes. So i have to make changes only at the producer level.

I am considering using snappy compression with batch.size to 5MB in my producer . Please let me know if this is the right option or any other way is available for my usecase. Thanks

Comment: What are you producing for the message to be so large? Using compression will help but you will probably run into the same issue further down the road.

Comment: thanks for the response ,the messages come from another system and average message size is just 20Kb , but there are some with 5 to 6 MB sizes. that's where i get the issues.

Comment: Why does the message size vary so much? Is it possible to split these large messages into multiple payloads using the same key?

Comment: yeah that is something i have to try if there is no other way , thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a message is sent from producer, it is stored at kafka broker and consumed by the consumer.
Producer -> Broker -> Consumer

So, if you want to send large messages from Kafka, you need to change the configuration setting for both broker and consumer.
a) For Broker:

```
message.max.bytes=15728640 
replica.fetch.max.bytes=15728640
```

b) For Consumer:

```
fetch.message.max.bytes=15728640
```

But since you don't have access to broker and consumer, you can set the compression property at **Producer or Topic level.**

Set the compression property at **topic level**:

```
./bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --config compression.type=gzip --topic topic_name
```

or set the property `compression.type = gzip` in **Kafka Producer** Client API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am already considering compression , but concerned about few things below,
1) i learned that if the message size is bigger than the batch size , those messages will never be batched and compressed.
2) so , if i have a message size with 3MB , and batch size as 2 MB , that message will never be batched and compressed and that message would still be rejected .

any idea how to handle it ?

Comment: Also , even if i manage to send this huge message compressed in 2 MB batches , will the consumer or broker reject it based on its own max request size ?  and should my batch size be less than the consumer/broker config ?